# Foreign key from multiple tables

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

I am thinking of three tables;

Employee with emp_id an, emp_name and other related data.

and

Person table with person_id, person_name and other related data.

and

GroupList with grp_list_id, member_id (either emp_id or person_id) and is_employee (true for employee and false for person) and other related data.

This is the first time I am trying to do a table whose foreign key can come from two different tables.  Can someone please suggest the best way to achieve it?

Comment: Please create a separate question for the PrimeFaces part. Two questions in one is confusing for other readers

Comment: Is the database tables structure set already, or are you designing it now?  What do the entities you need to work with look like?

Comment: @Chris I am still designing it.

Comment: @Kukeltje I see what you mean.

Comment: If you are designing it, what do you need it to do?  What is the purpose of a different Employee, Person and GroupList with respect to your business objects?  ie, why isn't an Employee also a Person?

Comment: You might want to look into EcipseLInk's variable mapping: http://eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/jpa/extensions/a_variableonetoone.htm though I'm confident you can redesign your tables to make it unneeded.